# constructing regexp expression to check for particular text-database format

Tags: python, regex, matlab

let's assume I have a text file which acts as a simple database by using the `|` symbol to delimit database columns:

```
|some text| 234| other field| bla| 1232|
```

I want to construct an regexp expression that will

- check how many fields are present in each line (by counting the occurrence of the `|` symbol)
- check which fields are empty (no text between two `|` symbols)
- will return each fields value
- will strip white space from around field value. But be careful, empty field should not be stripped!

here's two examples to illustrate what I want:

```
line = |some text| 234| other field| bla| 1232|
output = my_regexp(line)
disp(output)
  'some text', '234', 'other field', 'bla', '1232'
```

now the same, but this time field 3 is empty:

```
line2 = |some text| 234|  | bla| 1232|
output = my_regexp(line)
disp(output)
  'some text', '234', '', 'bla', '1232'
```

I've tried the following

```
values = regexp(regexprep(line '[\s]', ''), '\|', 'split')
```

but unfortunately this solution does not

- check how many `|` are present
- does not preserve the field order of returned values, because an empty field is ignored
- tell me what field is empty

I've never built a complex regexp rule and appreciate your input!

Comment: Why did you tag this Python? The line of example code appears to be Matlab- do you want a Python solution?

Comment: @DavidRobinson I don't care whether it's a matlab or python solution. I appreciate both. Hope that's ok!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using `line.split` as follows:

```
values = [v.strip() for v in line.split("|")[1:-1]]
num_fields = len(values)
num_empty_fields = values.count("")
```

To get a list of indices of the empty fields:

```
indices_empty_fields = [i for i, f in enumerate(values) if f == ""]
```

To use regular expressions, replace the calculation of `values` with:

```
import re
values = re.split("\s*\|\s*", line)[1:-1]
```

Comment: @DavidRobinson yeah man, now you are confusing me. I like your solution, but now you ended up using regexps again :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Mostly I meant that you don't need to use the regex to count the number of fields or the number that were empty, but you are right! Edited

Comment: @DavidRobinson is there an easy way to find out which field is empty by accessing `values`?

Comment: @memyself: When you say "which field is empty": You mean a list of indices of empty fields?

Comment: @DavidRobinson yes. so using my second example for my positing, I would expect to know that field number 3 is empty, so that would translate to index 2.

Comment: @DavidRobinson is there a way to automatically strip off white space that might be around a field's entry? Or do I have to parse `values` for these cases separately?

Comment: @memyself: see latest edit. (Technically stripping whitespace, if done right after splitting, removes the need for using any regular expressions earlier).

Comment: @memyself: In fact, I changed the answer to skip using regex at all.

Comment: @DavidRobinson can you leave both solutions in your answer? I think it would be great two see two ways of solving this problem (and maybe add why one way is better than the other?)

Comment: @memyself: Sure I added it back in, but there's really not a lot of difference between the approaches (enough to judge one being better than the other in some objective sense).

Answer (score 3):

I would not use regular expressions here at all; they are too complex a tool for such a simple job.

Simply split on the pipe symbol:

```
>>> '|some text| 234| other field| bla| 1232|'.split('|')
['', 'some text', ' 234', ' other field', ' bla', ' 1232', '']
```

Discard the first and last values, strip the rest to remove whitespace, and you have your columns:

```
>>> example = '|some text| 234| other field| bla| 1232|'
>>> columns = map(lambda s: s.strip(), example.split('|')[1:-1])
>>> columns
['some text', '234', 'other field', 'bla', '1232']
```

To count columns without splitting, simply use the `.count()` function, subtract 1:

```
>>> example.count('|') - 1
5
```

or take the `len` of the column output:

```
>>> len(columns)
5
```

Want to count empty columns? Split on those columns and count the empty ones:

```
>>> columns.count('')
0
```

Or for your second line:

```
>>> line2 = '|some text| 234|  | bla| 1232|'
>>> columns_line2 = map(lambda s: s.strip(), line2.split('|')[1:-1])
>>> columns_line2
['some text', '234', '', 'bla', '1232']
>>> columns_line2.count('')
1
```